# Scope Issues in Getting Jquery-File-Upload to work with AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to implement a multi-file upload feature and came across this http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html.

In my form, I am using `ng-switch` to load in different parts of the form as part of a form wizard. The second part of the form requires the user to upload pictures and this is where things start to break for me. I understand why it's breaking -- `ng-switch`, with many other directives, creates a new scope. The work around is to use objects as opposed to "writing" directly to the scope -- `$scope.booking.amount` as opposed to `$scope.amount`

So how do I get jquery-file-upload, or any other 3rd party library for that matter, to "bind" correctly to my object and prevent these scope issues?

Relevant parts of jquery-file-upload:

- https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/app.js
- https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload-angular.js

Relevant parts of my code:

**View**

```
<div data-ng-switch="getCurrentStep()" data-ng-animate="'slide'">
<div data-ng-switch-when="one">
<!-- First part of form -->
    <textarea data-ng-model="viewing.remarks" type="text" rows="4" cols="10" placeholder="A short description of the property"></textarea>
</div>
<div data-ng-switch-when="two">
<!-- Second part of form -->
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple data-ng-disabled="disabled">
    <ul class="inline-list">
        <li data-ng-repeat="file in queue" data-ng-switch data-on="!!file.thumbnailUrl">
        <div class="preview" data-ng-switch-when="true">
            <a data-ng-href="{{file.url}}" title="{{file.name}}" download="{{file.name}}" data-gallery>
                  <img data-ng-src="{{file.thumbnailUrl}}" alt="">
                </a>         
                <a href="" class="text-center" data-ng-click="file.$cancel()" data-ng-hide="!file.$cancel">Cancel</a>
        </div>
        <div class="preview" data-ng-switch-default data-file-upload-preview="file"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Controller**

The main thing is I have a viewing object which is called from a service.

```
$scope.viewing = new Viewing()
```

So in the current code context, how do I get `$scope.queue`, which is from jquery-file-upload, talking to my `$scope.viewing` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is actually quite straight forward.

First I have to add the directive `data-file-upload="options"` inside the new scope created by the ng-switch. So this means moving it from `<form data-file-upload ....>` to a div inside the second ng-switch.

After that, to bind it to my object it's simply

```
$scope.queue = [];
$scope.viewing.fileQueue = $scope.queue
```

`$scope.queue` originates from the blueimp angular file and needed to be initialized in my controller first.